# Find and prove a formula for 1mod3 ∩ 1mod7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I have tried looking at similar problems where A is a subset of B iff A ∩ B =A. But it does not seem to work. What type of formula should I be looking for and proving?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is it asking for $\{n|n\equiv1\bmod3 $ and $7\}$?

Comment: Your notation is not standard.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Chinese's remainder teorem. In particular, because $\gcd(3,7)=1$, we can say that the common soltions to the Chinese system are given by:
$$x\equiv 1\mod 21$$Or, in other words: $$x=21k+1, k\in Z$$